# Proxy Authentication Required NLTK download

Tags: python, nltk

I have installed python 2.7.3 on a Windows 8, 64 bit machine, sublime text and nltk 3.0.1 with the following steps:

- Install Setuptools:
  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools and run ez_setup.py from the directory stored in python27 (from CMD prompt)
- Install NLTK: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk
  In nltk directory run setup.py to install nltk (from CMD prompt)
- Change the environmental variables to %PYTHONPATH%;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\Lib\lib2to3;C:\Python27\Scripts with PYTHONPATH with C:\Python27

Test installation: Start>Python34, then type import nltk
in sublime type

```
import nltk
nltk.set_proxy('xxx.xx.xx.xx:yy',('username','pwd'))
nltk.download()
```

However, I am met with the following error:

```
HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required (The ISA Server requires   authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy Filter is denied.
```

Despite giving the proxy details why am I getting this error?

Please help,
Arc.

Comment: Wrong proxy credentials.

Comment: Where did you see an instruction to add proxy info?

Comment: I saw the instructions in http://www.nltk.org/data.html since i am using proxy server at college I needed to use the instruction above to solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

Try this format instead for setting the proxy details:

```
import nltk
nltk.set_proxy('https://username:password@proxy.example.com:port')
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This work for me on macOS 10.15

Search for 'Install Certificates.command' in finder and open it.

Now,

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

It will open the NLTK downloader then you can select and download the required package.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same issue but i could able to solve with this

```
> nltk.set_proxy('xxx.xx.xx.xx:yy' , 'username', 'passcode')
```