# Setting up nltk data from github repo

Tags: python, nltk, nltk-book

I was following [nltk book chapter 1](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html). I am able to install `nltk` (`import nltk`) but was not able to download the book corpus by running `nltk.download()`. It gave me `getattrinfo failed` error. So I started quickly going through commands in chapter without executing those commands, as most example given requires book corpus.

But now I want to try [`FreqDist` example](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html#frequency-distributions).

[While running `FreqDist`, I realized that I have not done `from nltk.book import *`](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html#frequency-distributions). So, I have again tried to install book corpus. Now, I am absolutely exhausted trying out different solutions given in various posts to fix `getattrinfo failed` error that occurs while importing nltk data. (I [tried setting up corporate proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31181620/1317018), [changing nltk downloader source link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27764910/1317018) among many other stuff)

So instead of following route of using nltk downloader, I tried doing possibly something weird. I downloaded [zip from `https://github.com/nltk/`](https://codeload.github.com/nltk/nltk/zip/develop) , extracted and then ran `setup.py` inside it.

Now when I run `from nltk.book import *`, I get following output:

```
>>> from nltk.book import *
*** Introductory Examples for the NLTK Book ***
Loading text1, ..., text9 and sent1, ..., sent9
Type the name of the text or sentence to view it.
Type: 'texts()' or 'sents()' to list the materials.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\path\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 63, in __load
    try: root = nltk.data.find('corpora/%s' % zip_name)
  File "D:\path\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 641, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError:
**********************************************************************
  Resource 'corpora/gutenberg.zip/gutenberg/' not found.  Please
  use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>>
  nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\593932/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\path\\Softwares\\python\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\\python-3.4.4.amd64\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\path\\Softwares\\python\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\\python-3.4.4.amd64\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\593932\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
**********************************************************************

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\path\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\book.py", line 20, in <module>
    text1 = Text(gutenberg.words('melville-moby_dick.txt'))
  File "D:\path\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 99, in __getattr__
    self.__load()
  File "D:\path\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 64, in __load
    except LookupError: raise e
  File "D:\path\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 61, in __load
    root = nltk.data.find('corpora/%s' % self.__name)
  File "D:\path\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 641, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError:
**********************************************************************
  Resource 'corpora/gutenberg' not found.  Please use the NLTK
  Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\593932/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\path\\Softwares\\python\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\\python-3.4.4.amd64\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\path\\Softwares\\python\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\\python-3.4.4.amd64\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\593932\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
>>>
```

I manually copy pasted the `nltk` folder which also contains `book.py` in various folders listed above:

```
- 'C:\\Users\\593932/nltk_data'
- 'C:\\nltk_data'
- 'D:\\nltk_data'
- 'E:\\nltk_data'
- 'D:\\path\\Softwares\\python\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\\python-3.4.4.amd64\\nltk_data'
- 'D:\\path\\Softwares\\python\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\\python-3.4.4.amd64\\lib\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Users\\593932\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
```

But no use. How can I get this book stuff imported in my interpreter environment from zip downloaded from github, without requiring to use nltk downloader? Is it even possible?

Comment: First update your NLTK version, your version is outdated, `pip install -U nltk`. Next in the new version, you'll see something like `import nltk; nltk.download('popular')`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211525/how-do-i-download-nltk-data

Answer (score 0):

See [NLTK Documentation](https://www.nltk.org/data.html#manual-installation) under Manual Installation:

> Create a folder nltk_data, e.g. C:\nltk_data, or /usr/local/share/nltk_data, and subfolders chunkers, grammars, misc, sentiment, taggers, corpora, help, models, stemmers, tokenizers.
> Download individual packages from https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ (see the “download” links). Unzip them to the appropriate subfolder. For example, the Brown Corpus, found at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/corpora/brown.zip is to be unzipped to nltk_data/corpora/brown.
> Set your NLTK_DATA environment variable to point to your top level nltk_data folder.